# What does "at%" refer to in sol-gel method?

Tags: solutions

I'm reading on the preparation of ZnO thin films for UV stimulated emission and I found a method called Sol-Gel. During this I found a paragraph saying, " the ration Ag/Zn in the sol is 3 at%......". so I want to know what at% refer to.

Comment: Same question on Physics SE - cross posting is generally frowned on since questions can be migrated to the better SE...

Answer (score 1):

Atomic percentage. It can be converted to weight percentage (wt%) too.